# Linking to registration email URL after a signup form

Tags: registration, flow, signup

So, today I was working on the 'thank you for... page' at the company that hired me. It is a page that is shown after the user 'requests' an offer for a certain treatment. Because of privacy rights we need to confirm that email before we can contact them.

While testing, I got an idea. We already know the domain of the email (for instance some populair: Outlook / gmail / hotmail / yahoo etc.). Why not make the email a link?

#### On the page we currently show the following text*:

Thank you for showing intrest in [product x]. We send an email to 'example@gmail.com' for verification. Please follow the instructions in the email.

*roughly translated.

### My Question

Are there any negative UX related consequences for making `example@gmail.com` link to gmail.com?

I can only think of these 2, that do not seem to big:

- User miss typed their email. (Even this can be checked with some code. For instance if its @gmial.com dont make it linkable)
- The users adres used in the signup is not their primary email.

I've never seen this used in the websites i register for, so I'm curious if I'm missing something?

For instance, if you register on mobile and you link to gmail.com. Gmail.com will ask you to open the app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A significant drawback that I could see (which could be confirmed with some testing) is that this link would be misunderstood by not communicating what it does.

If I were to try and assume different personas...

> **As a tech savvy user:**
>
> I see an email address that is styled as a link, I assume it's a `mailto:email@example.com` link (created by the web developer, or automatically by my browser), which would open my default mail provider to compose a new email to that address.
>
> **As a user competent with routine tasks:**
>
> You tell me you sent me an email; got it, no problem. I know how to do that: I need to open my email app/click on my web bookmark and find the email, ignoring the provided link altogether.
>
> **As a user who finds difficulty in interacting with technology:**
>
> The hyperlinked email address provides me with no instructions or information on what it will do, and I'm scared I might do something wrong, or afraid I may get lost if I click it.

Sure, these may be exaggerated caricatures, but these or similar issues could come up during some preliminary user testing, and worth considering.

#### Instead...

I'd recommend giving a descriptive call-to-action that explains exactly what it will do so the user is well informed of what this will do.

[image: Confirmation message, instructing user to navigate to their email provider, with a link to do so]

Comment: yup, I've seen this before in the wild. I guess we stopped seeing them because let's be honest, how many devices with email apps each of us have? I have an inbox that if someone sends me on it, I get three notifications, 2 on mobile and 1 on desktop :) ... so life is too good not for that help tip